# XDocument select distinct elements using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am trying to get a distinct list of elements but it always returns everything.

Xml:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <unit>CAN</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>KG</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>KG</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>PKT</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>CAN</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>PKT</unit>
    </row>
    <row>
        <unit>KG</unit>
    </row>
</root>
```

Linq:

```
List<XElement> elements = (from e in xdoc.Descendants("row").Elements()
     where e.Name.Equals("unit")
     select e).Distinct().ToList();
```

Expected output:
elements list should contain 3 items

```
    <unit>CAN</unit>
    <unit>KG</unit>
    <unit>PKT</unit>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Distinct()` does not know what part of the `XElement` to compare, so it will just compare the object reference. Since all XElements are separate objects, no matter the content, it will return them all.

You either have to define an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) that allows it to compare them (probably the preferred way to do it) or just use GroupBy that can take a lambda that will allow it to compare the actual Value instead;

```
var elements = (from e in xdoc.Root.Elements("row").Elements("unit")
                select e).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First());
```

Output:

```
<unit>CAN</unit>
<unit>KG</unit>
<unit>PKT</unit>
```

Comment: It worked, I just had to add .ToList() to the end.
...x.First()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var query = (from e in xml.Root.Elements("row").Elements("unit")
         select e).GroupBy(e => e.Value).Select(x => x.First());
```

EDIT: Whoops-- I overlooked the 'distinct' requirement. Amending the above answer using **Joachim Isaksson**'s lambda expression. Here's the new output:

```
<unit>CAN</unit> 
<unit>KG</unit> 
<unit>PKT</unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

select e.Value,

```
   from e in xdoc.Descendants("row").Elements()
 where e.Name.Equals("unit")
 select e.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would group and take the first item in each group:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml");

    List<XElement> distinctUnits =
        (from unit in doc.Root.Elements("row").Elements("unit")
         group unit by (string)unit into g
         select g.First()).ToList();

    foreach (XElement unit in distinctUnits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(unit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get the result

```
      List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();

     foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name == "unit").Select(c=>c))
        {
            if (elements.Where(c => c.Value == item.Value).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                elements.Add(item);
            }
        }


  <unit>CAN</unit>
  <unit>KG</unit>
   <unit>PKT</unit>
```