# How do i change my LINQ query to show the correct XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I am having trouble printing the correct XML. the idea is to create an XML out of a query.

I have two classes; Track and CD. Track contains attributes of a track and CD contains a name and artist attribute and a List<Track. I have added three hardcoded tracks to a CD object. I am trying to query over an XML that contains the whole album and print a new XML that shows all tracks in that album, excluding the hard coded ones in my CD object. This is my code so far:

```
class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }

    public static List<Track> CreateTrackList()
    {
        List<Track> tracks = new List<Track>
        {
            new Track { Title = "Numb", Artist = "Linkin Park", Length = new TimeSpan(00, 03, 05)},
            new Track { Title = "Breaking the Habit", Artist = "Linkin Park", Length = new TimeSpan(00, 03, 16)},
            new Track { Title = "Faint", Artist = "Linkin Park", Length = new TimeSpan(00, 02, 42)}
        };
        return tracks;
    }

}

    class CD
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Track> Tracks { get; set; }

    public CD(string artist, string name, List<Track> tracks)
    {
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Tracks = tracks;
    }
}

        List<Track> tracks = Track.CreateTrackList();
        CD cd = new CD("Linkin Park", "Meteora", tracks);
        String xmlString;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlString = wc.DownloadString(@"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=b5cbf8dcef4c6acfc5698f8709841949&artist=Linkin+Park&album=Meteora");
        }
        XDocument myXMLDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = from track in myXMLDoc.Descendants("track")
                                       from t in cd.Tracks
                                       where track.Element("name").Value != t.Title && track.Element("artist").Element("name").Value == t.Artist
                                       select track;
        foreach (XElement t in query1)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(t);
        }
```

When i run the code i get the following XML output:

```
<track rank="1">
  <name>Foreword</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Foreword</url>
  <duration>13</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="1">
  <name>Foreword</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Foreword</url>
  <duration>13</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="1">
  <name>Foreword</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Foreword</url>
  <duration>13</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="2">
  <name>Don't Stay</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Don%27t+Stay</url>
  <duration>188</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="2">
  <name>Don't Stay</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Don%27t+Stay</url>
  <duration>188</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="2">
  <name>Don't Stay</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Don%27t+Stay</url>
  <duration>188</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="3">
  <name>Somewhere I Belong</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Somewhere+I+Belong</url>
  <duration>214</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="3">
  <name>Somewhere I Belong</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Somewhere+I+Belong</url>
  <duration>214</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="3">
  <name>Somewhere I Belong</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Somewhere+I+Belong</url>
  <duration>214</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="4">
  <name>Lying from You</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Lying+from+You</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="4">
  <name>Lying from You</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Lying+from+You</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="4">
  <name>Lying from You</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Lying+from+You</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="5">
  <name>Hit the Floor</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Hit+the+Floor</url>
  <duration>164</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="5">
  <name>Hit the Floor</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Hit+the+Floor</url>
  <duration>164</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="5">
  <name>Hit the Floor</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Hit+the+Floor</url>
  <duration>164</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="6">
  <name>Easier to Run</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Easier+to+Run</url>
  <duration>204</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="6">
  <name>Easier to Run</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Easier+to+Run</url>
  <duration>204</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="6">
  <name>Easier to Run</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Easier+to+Run</url>
  <duration>204</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="7">
  <name>Faint</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Faint</url>
  <duration>162</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="7">
  <name>Faint</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Faint</url>
  <duration>162</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="8">
  <name>Figure.09</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Figure.09</url>
  <duration>197</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="8">
  <name>Figure.09</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Figure.09</url>
  <duration>197</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="8">
  <name>Figure.09</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Figure.09</url>
  <duration>197</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="9">
  <name>Breaking the Habit</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Breaking+the+Habit</url>
  <duration>196</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="9">
  <name>Breaking the Habit</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Breaking+the+Habit</url>
  <duration>196</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="10">
  <name>From the Inside</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/From+the+Inside</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="10">
  <name>From the Inside</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/From+the+Inside</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="10">
  <name>From the Inside</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/From+the+Inside</url>
  <duration>175</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="11">
  <name>Nobody's Listening</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Nobody%27s+Listening</url>
  <duration>178</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="11">
  <name>Nobody's Listening</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Nobody%27s+Listening</url>
  <duration>178</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="11">
  <name>Nobody's Listening</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Nobody%27s+Listening</url>
  <duration>178</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="12">
  <name>Session</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Session</url>
  <duration>144</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="12">
  <name>Session</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Session</url>
  <duration>144</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="12">
  <name>Session</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Session</url>
  <duration>144</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="13">
  <name>Numb</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Numb</url>
  <duration>188</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
<track rank="13">
  <name>Numb</name>
  <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park/_/Numb</url>
  <duration>188</duration>
  <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
  <artist>
    <name>Linkin Park</name>
    <mbid>f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419</mbid>
    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Linkin+Park</url>
  </artist>
</track>
```

As you can see it shows all tracks 3 times and the tracks in t.Title are shown twice. How can i change my code so it shows every track once, except the tracks that are in t.Title?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select e.g. the C language tag instead of C#. Also please learn how to [edit] your questions to fix problems.

Comment: When you preform foreach (XElement t in query1), you probably want to do a group by. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097185/xdocument-select-distinct-elements-using-linq

Comment: From : track.Element("name").Value != t.Title  To : track.Element("name").Value == t.Title  You are using not equal instead of equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing cross-join, but based on the description looks like you are looking for simple filtering in 'where', somethink like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = from track in myXMLDoc.Descendants("track")
                               where !cd.Tracks.Any(an=>
                                        an.Title == track.Element("name").Value
                                        && track.Element("artist").Element("name").Value == an.Artist)
                                       select track;
```

Comment: This makes perfect sence and works perfectly. Thank you very much!